# Looking for matching leading values in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists. They start out as being empty lists and over the course of my program, I add to the list by inserting values to the front. It's for a card game. Similar to solitaire. So the list of lists starts with an Ace and ends with a King. What I am currently trying to do is determine when the player has actually won the game, this would mean when the King is the first card for every list in the list of lists. I'm having trouble doing this. Currently, when I loop through my function, once one list has the king value, it lets me know that I have won.

```
BANNER = WINNER!!
foundations = [ [], [], [], [] ]

for lst in foundations[:]:
    for item in lst:
        if item.rank() == 13: # the rank of a king
            print(BANNER)
            return True
else:
    return False
```

what I'm looking for is:

```
when foundations = [ [13], [13], [13], [13] ] # all four list containing king

then the loop returns True
```

Any tips how to stop the code from giving me false hopes and letting me know when I've actually won the game?

Comment: i think it's easier if you reverse your logic. that is: you haven't won if any of the lists don't start with a king. otherwise, you win.

Comment: Thank you, that is good way to look at it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you return from the function as soon as `if item.rank() == 13` condition is `True`, which is not enough for the win.

You also appear to be stepping through all of the list values, but you only need to step through the first one in each list.

So the code you are looking for is

```
for list in foundations:
    if list[0] != 13:
        return False  # this is definitely not a win
return True # this code will only work if return False didn't work
```

In this case, I assumed each `list` has at least one value. Depending on your problem, you may want to work around this assumption.